# SQL query execution - different outcomes on Windows and Linux

Tags: mysql, sql, windows, linux

The following is generated query from Hibernate (except I replaced the list of fields with *):

```
select *
from
    resource resource0_,
    resourceOrganization resourceor1_ 
where
    resource0_.active=1 
    and resource0_.published=1 
    and (
        resource0_.resourcePublic=1 
        or resourceor1_.resource_id=resource0_.id 
        and resourceor1_.organization_id=2 
        and (
            resourceor1_.resource_id=resource0_.id 
            and resourceor1_.forever=1 
            or resourceor1_.resource_id=resource0_.id 
            and (
                current_date between resourceor1_.startDate and resourceor1_.endDate
            )
        )
    )
```

Currently I have 200+ records in both the Windows and Linux databases and currently for each record, the following happens to be true:
active = 1
published = 1
resourcePublic = 1

When I run this directly in a SQL client, this SQL query gets me all the matching records on Windows but none on Linux. I've MySQL 5.1 on both Windows and Linux.

If I apply the Boolean logic, (true and true and (true or whatever)), I expect the outcome to be true. It indeed is true on Windows but false on Linux!!!

If I modify the query as the following, it works on both Windows and Linux:

```
select *
from
    resource resource0_
where
    resource0_.active=1 
    and resource0_.published=1 
    and (
        resource0_.resourcePublic=1 
    )
```

So, just the presence of conditions related to resourceOrganization is making the query bring 0 results on Linux and I expected that since it is the second part of an 'or' condition whose first part is true, the outcome should be true.

Any idea why this difference in behavior between the 2 OSs and why what should obviously work on Linux doesn't!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you 100% sure this is a platform issue as opposed to something else - encoding, user rights.....

Comment: SQL is platform independent--this is very likely to be a difference in data between the instance on Windows vs Linux.  Take mysqldumps of both, then restore the Windows dump to the Linux instance & test again--should work as it did on Windows.

Comment: Since you're using `current_date()`, check the dates on the two systems. Are they in sync? Also, check your clients. Some clients don't convert 1 and 0 to Boolean.

Comment: And please stop using that implied join syntax. It is subject to error (Accidental cross joins) is harder to maintain (was that a deliberate cross join or is it a bug? NOw I need a left join, what do I do, hint don't mix implicit and explicit together  in the same query)) and a very poor programming technique. It ihas also been outdated since 1992 for goodness sakes, there is not a single excuse for using it in 2010.

Comment: Select * is also a poor technique. It creates maintenance problems and wastes resources. Since you have a join you are returning at least two columns with the same data, wasteful, wasteful, wasteful. You should not use select * in production code.

Comment: Dear commenters, please read the first line: _The following is generated query from Hibernate_ :)

Comment: @dilip, if any answer was helpful please upvote or accept it.

Answer (score 2):

- Check the [case sensitivity and collation sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-general.html) ([Collation issues](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-collations.html))
- Check the [table case sensitivity](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html). In particular note that on windows the table names are case-insensitive and on Linux they are case-sensitive.
- Have you tried a simple test case on both system?

Answer (score 0):

Check that current_date() returns the same format in both plataforms

Answer (score 0):

Also don't forget to check the collation and case sensitivity, if one server uses a different collation to the other then you will have this same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that the second test query only consults the resource table not the resourceOrganisation table.

I suspect that the table resourceOrganisation is populated differently on the two machines, and the corresponding rows may not exist in your Linux MySQL.

What does this query return?

```
select *
from
    resource resource0_,
    resourceOrganization resourceor1_ 
where
    resource0_.active=1 
    and resource0_.published=1 
    and (
        resource0_.resourcePublic=1 
        or resourceor1_.resource_id=resource0_.id 
        and resourceor1_.organization_id=2 
    )
```